# Way to reveal additional form fields via CSS / HTML if user enters text in text form field?

Tags: html, css, forms, hidden-field

I'm trying to figure out a way to apply [this](https://css-tricks.com/exposing-form-fields-radio-button-css/) CSS / HTML approach for revealing additional form fields if a radio button or checkbox is selected, to a case where text is entered in a text form field.

I'm a novice and looking to avoid jquery and javascript at this time.

**Here's "my" CSS** (it works with "focus" if the text form field is selected, but once user tries to select the newly revealed form field, it disappears because the "focus" condition no longer applies):

```
.reveal-if-active {
  opacity: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked ~ .reveal-if-active,
input[type="text"]:focus ~ .reveal-if-active,
input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .reveal-if-active {
  opacity: 1;
  max-height: 600px; 
  overflow: visible;
```

The CSS line from above I'm seeking help with is:

```
input[type="text"]:focus ~ .reveal-if-active,
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<div>
    <p>Question I'm asking user to answer in the beginning form field is here</p>
    <div><input type="text" name="beginning-text-field" id="beginning-text-field" value="" placeholder="placeholder text goes here" /><br />
        <div class="reveal-if-active">
        <textarea id="revealed-form-field" name="revealed-form-field" value="" placeholder="Revealed placeholder text goes here" rows="4" maxchar="1000"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`input` cannot make use of the `:empty` pseudo-class in CSS, but you CAN take advantage of `:not` and `:placeholder-shown`.  Using those in combination you can achieve your desired results with the following:

**CSS**

```
.group label, .group input {
    display: block;
}

.elaborate {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
}

.question:not(:placeholder-shown) + .elaborate {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="group">
    <label for="q1">Question One</label>
    <input type="text" name="q1_answer" class="question" placeholder="Question 1 Answer" />
    <textarea name="q1_elaborate" class="elaborate" placeholder="Please elaborate"></textarea>
</div>
```

You can see a Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/7zp9pgqL/

Worth reading as well are usage restrictions on `:placeholder-shown` and `:not` pseudo-classes:

http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-placeholder-shown

http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-not-sel-list

Comment: A very helpful answer, but the usage restrictions, which you point out, are too great at this time

Comment: Understandable, but it does virtually eliminate your options to achieve this using only CSS.  You may need to consider allowing for a JavaScript solution.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, add this to your css:

```
.reveal-if-active:focus {
  max-height: none;
  opacity: 1;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

and remove div around textarea and asign div's class to textarea:

```
<div>
    <p>Question I'm asking user to answer in the beginning form field is here</p>
    <div><input type="text" name="beginning-text-field" id="beginning-text-field" value="" placeholder="placeholder text goes here" /><br />
        <textarea class="reveal-if-active" id="revealed-form-field" name="revealed-form-field" value="" placeholder="Revealed placeholder text goes here" rows="4" maxchar="1000"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sabeti05/45xmqsv9/)

Comment: This doesn't address the OPs secondary concern; allowing the newly-revealed field to remain visible even after the user has moved on to another field.